# Why jest mock not working if it isn't declared in 'it' scope

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, mocking

I created a simple typescript project with create-react-app..
And I try to create unit test with a jest's mock.
the class, I want to mock :

```
export class RestUserAPI {
  public constructor() {}
    getName(): string {
      return "MyUser";
    }
  }
}
```

the class I want to test

```
import {RestUserAPI} from "./RestUserAPI";

export class UserService {
  private userAPI: RestUserAPI;
  public constructor() {
    this.userAPI = new RestUserAPI();
  }

  getName(): string {
    return this.userAPI.getName();
  }
}
```

And my test which is not working

```
import { UserService } from './UserService';
import {RestUserAPI} from "./RestUserAPI";

const mockedUserName = 'mocked user name'

jest.mock('./RestUserAPI');
const RestUserAPIMock = RestUserAPI as jest.MockedClass<typeof RestUserAPI>;
RestUserAPIMock.mockImplementation(() => {
   return {
     getName: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockedUserName),
   };
});

describe("User Service", () => {
  let instance: UserService;
  beforeAll(() => {
    RestUserAPIMock.mockClear()
  });

  it("should get user name", () => {
    instance = new UserService();
    expect(instance.getName()).toBe(mockedUserName);
    expect(RestUserAPIMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

this code work, butt this is not what I want

```
import { UserService } from './UserService';
import {RestUserAPI} from "./RestUserAPI";

const mockedUserName = 'mocked user name'

jest.mock('./RestUserAPI');
const RestUserAPIMock = RestUserAPI as jest.MockedClass<typeof RestUserAPI>;

describe("User Service", () => {
  let instance: UserService;
  beforeAll(() => {
    RestUserAPIMock.mockClear()
  });

  it("should get user name", () => {
    RestUserAPIMock.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        getName: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockedUserName),
      };
    });

    instance = new UserService();
    expect(instance.getName()).toBe(mockedUserName);
    expect(RestUserAPIMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

What is my mistake?
How can I create a mock implementation for all my 'it' blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your assignment code should be inside a `beforeEach` or a `beforeAll` block, so if you move the `mockImplementation` code into the `beforeAll`, or into a separate `beforeEach` block inside your `describe` block, it should work.
You actually don’t need to clear the mocks in your `beforeAll` so you could remove that and replace it with the mocking code.

Comment: Thanks !  
I tried moving the mockImplementation into the beforeAll but it doesn't work (the return value is undefined).  
However, when I replace beforeAll with beforeEach, it works fine.

Comment: Don’t forget to mark the question as answered, unless you need me to alter my answer before you accept it.